# application-wide jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, facebook

I use some Facebook JS scripts for user authentification, etc. I want to place them in the properly unobtrusive way as application-wide scripts.

Currently I have the script as a partial and call it from my application header:

```
<%# render 'layouts/facebook_app_scripts' %>
```

The script works but is extremely obtrusive. I want to make it unobtrusive. This is especially important since I tap into all sorts of APIs and it's getting messy.

You don't need to see it in its entirety (if you need to see the script to answer this question, I don't think you'll be any help as this is a general question not script-specific)

You should know that it contains dynamically created links such as this one:

```
window.top.location = "<%= Facebook::SITE_URL.to_s %>/logout";
```

That means that putting this in a .js file in the assets/javascript folder isn't going to work, since .js files can't access rails-generated variables.

So how can I shift my javascript with dynamically-generated links from the rails view to an unobtrusive javascript file?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [this project](https://github.com/siong1987/facebook_js) to include all the Facebook JS SDK as a gem